# How can i find what cause a null exception ? I mean what line or where in the code the exception throw?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, directx, direct3d

I'm running my program and after some time it's working it's throwing this exception:

[image: Directx Exception]

I'm using directx in my program and also direct3d in the top of the form i did:

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
using Microsoft.DirectX;
```

And i'm using in my program with Direct3D.Sprite and Device and Texture PresentParameters and DisplayMode all connected to the DirectX.Direct3D

And in the exception message it's saying something about OnLostDevice() and others. But it dosen't give any specific line or where in the code the problem is.

Is there any way to find what cause the problem ?

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Sprite.OnLostDevice()
       at Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Sprite.OnParentLost(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device.raise_DeviceLost(Object i1, EventArgs i2)
       at Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device.Finalize()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: I can upload to my skydrive the whole project since the form the problem is, is big a lot of code and also the project it self i can't upload it to here. Maybe if someone will try to use my program he will be able to find and see what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For start put the `Configuration` of the project to `Debug`. At the moment you are in `Release` ! In your screenshot you can see it to the `Continue` button. After that you should `Debug` you project.

When you are in Debug, you can see the exact line which throw exception when you check the checkbox in `Debug/Exceptions/Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.

Comment: mybirthname ok i did what you said and now instead the null exception it's stopping and throw exception on the line: if (rgbValuesWithClouds[p] != rgbValuesWithoutClouds[p]) say Index was outside the bounds of the array could be this what made it to show the null exception before i did this changes ?

Comment: I mean could be this is the problem i just didn't see it untill now untill changed to debug and did the checkbox ?

Comment: I will solve this exception now i just wonder if the null before could be coming out of this exception ? I mean if this Index was outside the bounds of the array could be did the null before ?

Comment: yes this is the problem, post the whole code block when the exception happen. It will be best to post the whole method in your initial question. The problem is that for this p there is no element in this collection with this index

Comment: Ok i will or will make a new question for this exception.